# Total CPU usage - multicore system

Tags: linux, bash, cpu-usage

I am using xen and with `xen top` I get the total CPU usage in percentage:

```
      NAME  STATE   CPU(sec) CPU(%)     MEM(k) MEM(%)  MAXMEM(k) MAXMEM(%) VCPUS NETS NETTX(k) NETRX(k) VBDS   VBD_OO   VBD_RD   VBD_WR  VBD_RSECT  VBD_WSECT SSID

      VM1 -----r      25724  299.4    3025244   12.0   20975616      83.4    12    1 14970253 27308358    1        3   146585    92257   10835706    9976308    0
```

As you can see from above I see the CPU usage is 299 %, but how I can get the total CPU usage from a VM ?
`Top` doesn't show me the total usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We usually see 100% cpu per core.
I guess there are at least 3 cores/cpus.

try this to count cores:

```
grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

299% is the total cpu usage.

`sar` and `mpstat` are often used to display cpu usage of a system. Check that `systat` package is installed and display total cpu usage with:

```
$ mpstat 1 1
Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (debian)   05/01/2016      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

07:48:51 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
07:48:52 PM  all    0.12    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.38
Average:     all    0.12    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.38
```

If you agree that CPU utilisation is (100 - %IDLE):

```
$ mpstat 1 1 | awk '/^Average/ {print 100-$NF,"%"}'
0.52 %
```

Comment: I want to see the CPU usage in total across all of the cores.

Comment: @user3580316 I think that 299% is the total cpu usage (I do not know xen). `top` and `sar` are often used.

Comment: thanks. But it doesn't show the summary of the total cpu usage, only for usage for each cpu core.

Comment: @Jayjargot Sorry to re-open the question, is it always correct to use as standard 100-idle 
(In my case I have a system monitoring written as sh script in a huge server. 2xE5-2667 v4 8core)?